# matplotlib.pyplot.draw() and matplotlib.pyplot.show() have no effect

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

In the past I was able to do simple animations with matplotlib with a for loop, but this hasn't worked for some time now.

The standard answer is that you have to turn interactive mode on and/or force a redraw with `matplotlib.pyplot.draw()`. Here is my minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as mplot

mplot.ion()

fig = mplot.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for ii in np.arange(0,10):
    x = 200*np.random.rand(30)
    ax.plot(x)
    mplot.draw()
    filename = ("img_%d.png" % ii)
    mplot.savefig(filename)
```

When I run this in [Interactive Python Editor](http://www.iep-project.org/), I get one figure at the very end with all the plots in it (this also happens with `mplot.show()`)

When I run this in IPython 3.1 (with Python 3.3.5) from the command line, I get nothing at all.

The `mplot.savefig(filename)` line does seem to work, as the images are generated.

(It's possible this is a bug in the Qt4 backend.)

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting the line `matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')`. Works for me. Also works with `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')`. So it is a backend problem. There is [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423397) to do animations.

Comment: So you tried it with `matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')` and it didn't work for you either?